# NSURLAuthenticationChallenge issue

Tags: post, ios8, put, nsurlsession

I'm writing an app for a customer's web-service. The service is a cloud storage. So, one of my tasks is to upload all photo gallery to this cloud. While solving this problem, i faced the following issue. I'm using a **NSURLSession** for that, and some photo data receives **NSURLAuthenticationChallenge**. In my **NSURLSessionDataDelegate**, i've tried to do the following -

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
          task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition disposition, NSURLCredential        *credential))completionHandler
{
     NSLog(@"challenge recieved!") ;
     self.authentcationChallengeLock = true ;
     completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, [NSURLCredential   credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]);
}
```

But this helps for some photos, but doesn't help for another - **NSURLSession** simply stops executing. In my previous experience, i was uploading photos to different social networks servers or others customers servers and didn't faced this trouble. Algorithm of uploading has always been the same -

1. Using OAuth token, receive file server access token and address
2. Perform PUT or POST request

Moreover, photos passed NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, are uploading twice. What shall i say to server backend engineers to fix this strange behavior? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Please let me know how do you solve this issue.

Comment: @purnachandra.tech the startup failed, project closed - that's how )